# Initial Value of DateTimePicker wrong

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm probably missing something obvious but I can't see it.....

I have a DateTimePicker control (Winforms) to display just the Time HH:mm:ss of the DateTime. The properties are as follows

```
Checked = False
Format = Time
ShowCheckbox = False
ShowUpDown = True
Value = 28/10/2014 08:00
ApplicationSettings.PropertyBinding.Value = pickTime1
```

Where `pickTime1` is a user setting where `Properties.Settings.Default.pickTime1 = 28/10/2014 08:00`

I'm expecting the control to display 08:00:00 when the form first loads but it displays the current time. How do I ensure the user setting is displayed when first initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribe to the `Form.Load` event and set it in there:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.pickTime1;
}
```

This will display 8:00:00 AM.

If you want 08:00:00, change `Format` to `Custom`, and set the `CustomFormat` property to "hh:mm:ss".

Answer (score 1):

The DateTimePicker.Value must be changed either by code or by user input, otherwise it will set to the current date and time (i.e. DateTime.Now)